# floating number string formatting in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a float let say 8.8 and I want to format it into 0008.800

I read this http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

If I do

> '%06g'%(8.8)

I get
0008.8

but I still don't know how to include the other decimals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%f` not `%g`:

```
>>> '%08.3f'%(8.8)
'0008.800'
```

Where 8 is the width and 3 is the precision.

With new style [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> "{:08.3f}".format(8.8)
'0008.800'
```